# asp.net panel alternative

Tags: c#, asp.net, panel

Guys, I am trying to find a nice panel like control for ASP.NET. I'd like something that is skinned, similar to this control: http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxperienceDemos/RoundPanel/Appearance.aspx

However, I would like something that is free or at least low price (I don't need a $1,000 control toolkit just for a panel). Any one have any suggestions?

Comment: AjaxContolToolkit will help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a pretty good javascript program to make some pretty nice rounded divs with a drop shadow: http://www.ruzee.com/blog/shadedborder

Answer (score 2):

How about a div with rounded corners on a web-kit browser? IE is losing market share rapidly, so I wouldn't worry too much about it.

If you really must support rounded corners on IE, I suppose you could use something like the [jQuery rounded corners](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/corners) plugin. I'm sure other JavaScript frameworks have similar features.

Comment: BTW, I'm really excited about CSS3, and HTML5.

Comment: +1 from me. you dont need $$$ to do some fancy stuff. Some good CSS will just do the magic for you

Answer (score 1):

Hai,
[Ajax Rounded corner around a panel](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/RoundedCorners/RoundedCorners.aspx) ajaxcontroltoolkit its free